# Prevent duplicate insert on refresh without session?

Tags: visual-web-part

I'm working on SharePoint 2010 (using a visual web part). Is there any way to prevent duplicate inserts in a list when a page is refreshed using F5, without using session?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional PAR routine (POST And Redirect) works to get rid of these problems.

Comment: thx, but it is possible to accopmlish that in the same page without redirection

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could post and redirect back to the same page. The redirect will be treated as a new request, not a postback.

Comment: @Andy i want to keep some value soo i can show message for users like (email sent or not sent ...) how can i do this whene refreshing the same page.